# 64-bit enum flag in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

We are sending a 64-bit enum from our C# back-end to our clients browsers via Web API 2. One of the requirements for the application is that it should run on `Windows 10 x64 with ie11`. However when I start `ie11` I get two processes, one 64-bit and one 32-bit by default. Will a 64-bit enum work with ie11 or not? We do not wan't to go with the enum option if it can't handle more than 32 flags.

[image]

We are using `TypeScript` to handle flags and compiling it to ES5 with Webpack.

[What are enum Flags in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39359740/what-are-enum-flags-in-typescript)

We use TypeLITE to generate TypeScript definitions.

http://type.litesolutions.net/

C# model:

```
[Flags]
[TsEnum(Module = "Application")]
public enum ValidationErrorType : Int64
{
    None = 0,
    NoCaseForRenewalCycle = 1 << 0, // 1
    RegistrationNumberExists = 1 << 1, // 2
    ApplicationNumberMissing = 1 << 2, // 4
    FeeCalculationNoPrice = 1 << 3, // 8
    //...
}
```

TypeLite.Net4, Enums.ts:

```
namespace Application {
    export const enum ValidationErrorType {
        None = 0,
        NoCaseForRenewalCycle = 1,
        RegistrationNumberExists = 2,
        ApplicationNumberMissing = 4,
        FeeCalculationNoPrice = 8
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show definition of your 64-bit enum?

Comment: @Evk Updated with models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser process bitness doesn't matter here at all. But what matters is javascript doesn't have such thing as 64-bit integer. Javascript has `number` type, which is basically C# `double`. For that reason, javascript cannot safely represent integers bigger than 2^53-1 (`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` constant). Also all bit operators (`<<`, `|` etc) work with numbers as 32-bit integers, which also doesn't help this situation. For example, `1 << 32` evaluates to `1` in javascript.

So your 64-bit typescript enum is a minefield which will lead to potentially hard to detect bugs, and for that reason I'd avoid it.

If you cannot avoid it - you have to use some library which is able to work with 64-bit numbers, such as BigJS (but then I suppose you cannot use typescript `enum`).